# How to get starting of the URL using javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, url

I want to get the starting part of the URL. like i have a URL **http://abc.com/HdWedding2013/FlipBook1.aspx?BookID=24&Height=500** From here what i want is : **http://abc.com/HdWedding2013/** or **http://abc.com/** . I have tried the following example but its giving the all URL :

```
alert( document.URL );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get abc.com use `location.origin'

Refer: [location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location)

As for your Application base path, ( http://abc.com/HdWedding2013/), you will have to use some asp.net code

```
alert('<%=ResolveUrl("~") %>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `document.location.protocol + '//' + document.domain`

Comment: When i need the first option like abc.com/HdWedding2013 then?

Comment: You can use `document.location.pathname` to get the _path_, that is, the portion after the domain but excluding query string (after the ?). You will have to manually extract the portion of the path you need. I.e. there's no built in way to get 'a' if you path looks like /a/b/c

Answer (score 1):

may be you are looking for :`window.location.origin`
Or

```
document.location.protocol+'//www.'+document.location.hostname
```

Comment: This will not include some sort of folder structure. I think OP is asking for the path to the executing script

Comment: to get other part document.location.pathname and programatically you can reverse the string -> get substring from first index of '/' to the end of string and reverse it back...

Answer (score 0):

```
alert( window.location.protocol + '://' + window.location.hostname );
```